# Can bin() be overloaded like oct() and hex() in Python 2.6?

Tags: python, binary, overloading, python-2.6

In Python 2.6 (and earlier) the `hex()` and `oct()` built-in functions can be overloaded in a class by defining `__hex__` and `__oct__` special functions. However there is not a `__bin__` special function for overloading the behaviour of Python 2.6's new `bin()` built-in function.

I want to know if there is any way of flexibly overloading `bin()`, and if not I was wondering why the inconsistent interface?

I do know that the `__index__` special function can be used, but this isn't flexible as it can only return an integer. My particular use case is from the [bitstring](http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/) module, where leading zero bits are considered significant:

```
>>> a = BitString(length=12)       # Twelve zero bits
>>> hex(a)
'0x000'
>>> oct(a)
'0o0000'
>>> bin(a)
'0b0' <------ I want it to output '0b000000000000'
```

I suspect that there's no way of achieving this, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the short answer is 'No, `bin()` can't be overloaded like `oct()` and `hex()`.'

As to why, the answer must lie with Python 3.0, which uses `__index__` to overload `hex()`, `oct()` and `bin()`, and has removed the `__oct__` and `__hex__` special functions altogether.

So the Python 2.6 `bin()` looks very much like it's really a Python 3.0 feature that has been back-ported without much consideration that it's doing things the new Python 3 way rather than the old Python 2 way. I'd also guess that it's unlikely to get fixed, even if it is considered to be a bug.

Answer (score 12):

As you've already discovered, you can't override `bin()`, but it doesn't sound like you need to do that.  You just want a 0-padded binary value.  Unfortunately in python 2.5 and previous, you couldn't use "%b" to indicate binary, so you can't use the "%" string formatting operator to achieve the result you want.

Luckily python 2.6 does offer what you want, in the form of the new [str.format()](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-formatting) method.  I believe that this particular bit of line-noise is what you're looking for:

```
>>> '{0:010b}'.format(19)
'0000010011'
```

The syntax for this mini-language is under "[format specification mini-language](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)" in the docs.  To save you some time, I'll explain the string that I'm using:

1. parameter zero (i.e. `19`) should be formatted, using
2. a magic "`0`" to indicate that I want 0-padded, right-aligned number, with
3. 10 digits of precision, in
4. binary format.

You can use this syntax to achieve a variety of creative versions of alignment and padding.

Comment: Thanks, that's useful to know. I have though already managed to get the output in the form I wanted, I just couldn't get the bin function to return it back to me. Your str.format method is considerably more concise than the method I used though!

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258330/converting-from-hex-to-binary-without-losing-leading-0s-python

Answer (score 1):

The bin function receives it's value from the object's `__index__` function.  So for an object, you can define the value converted to binary, but you can't define the format of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the same behaviour as for hex and oct by overriding/replacing the built in bin() function with your own implementation that attempted to call **bin** on the object being passed and fell back to the standard bin() function if the object didn't provide **bin**. However, on the basis that explicit is better than implicit, coding your application to depend on a custom version of bin() is probably not a good idea so maybe just give the function a different name e.g.

```
def mybin(n):
    try:
        return n.__bin__()
    except AttributeError:
        return bin(n)
```

As for why the inconsistency in the interface, I'm not sure. Maybe it's because bin() was added more recently so it's a slight oversight?