# Converting from hex to binary without losing leading 0's python

Tags: python, binary, hex

I have a hex value in a string like

```
h = '00112233aabbccddee'
```

I know I can convert this to binary with:

```
h = bin(int(h, 16))[2:]
```

However, this loses the leading 0's. Is there anyway to do this conversion without losing the 0's? Or is the best way to do this just to count the number of leading 0's before the conversion then add it in afterwards.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need the `0`'s?

Comment: I'm using the value h later as a key to a dictionary. The key however has all of the leading 0's.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason you're using a binary string representation of the value rather than an integer for the dictionary key?

Comment: @WayneWerner: I was looking for this so I can easily compare 50 binary numbers and look for bits that aren't changing.  `[bin(x).rjust(20) for x in a]` is good enough.

Comment: related: [Convert binary to ASCII and vice versa](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7396849/4279)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to keep those leading zeros by default.

Each hex digit translates to 4 binary digits, so the length of the new string should be exactly 4 times the size of the original.

```
h_size = len(h) * 4
```

Then, you can use `.zfill` to fill in zeros to the size you want:

```
h = ( bin(int(h, 16))[2:] ).zfill(h_size)
```

Comment: I think this gave me 3 extra 0's for some reason

Comment: Ah nevermind it works perfectly. I wasn't counting the 0's before the first non zero hex number. Thanks.

Comment: @root: unrelated: don't reuse `h` name for different things e.g., use `bits` name for the result: `bits = bin(int(h, 16))[2:].zfill(len(h) * 4)`

Answer (score 15):

This is actually quite easy in Python, since it doesn't have any limit on the size of integers. Simply prepend a `'1'` to the hex string, and strip the corresponding `'1'` from the output.

```
>>> h = '00112233aabbccddee'
>>> bin(int(h, 16))[2:]  # old way
'1000100100010001100111010101010111011110011001101110111101110'
>>> bin(int('1'+h, 16))[3:]  # new way
'000000000001000100100010001100111010101010111011110011001101110111101110'
```

Comment: Been looking for exactly this for an hour!

Comment: Why is this not an accepted answer.

Comment: @foobar you'll notice it was posted 3 years after the accepted answer - don't remember what prompted me to make an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the same but padding to 4 bindigits each hexdigit

```
''.join(bin(int(c, 16))[2:].zfill(4) for c in h)
```

Answer (score 0):

A newbie to python such as I would proceed like so

```
datastring = 'HexInFormOfString'
```

Padding to accommodate preceding zeros if any, when python converts string to Hex.

```
datastrPadded = 'ffff' + datastring
```

Convert padded value to binary.

```
databin = bin(int(datastrPadded,16))
```

Remove 2bits ('0b') that python adds to denote binary + 16 padded bits .

```
databinCrop = databin[18:]
```

Answer (score 0):

This converts a hex string into a binary string. Since you want the length to be dependent on the original, this may be what you want.

```
data = ""
while len(h) > 0:
    data = data + chr(int(h[0:2], 16))
    h = h[2:]
print h
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed integer as input and pure hex/bin strings out with the prefixs '0b' and '0x' so my general solution is this:

```
def pure_bin(data, no_of_bits=NO_OF_BITS):
    data = data + 2**(no_of_bits)
    return bin(data)[3:]

def pure_hex(data, no_of_bits=NO_OF_BITS):
    if (no_of_bits%4) != 0:
        no_of_bits = 4*int(no_of_bits / 4) + 4
    data = data + 2**(no_of_bits)
    return hex(data)[3:]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
hexa = '91278c4bfb3cbb95ffddc668d995bfe0'
binary = bin(int(hexa, 16))[2:]
print binary
hexa_dec = hex(int(binary, 2))[2:]
print hexa_dec
```