# converting dataframe from Hex to binary in using python

Tags: python, pandas, binary, hex

I am pretty new to Python and pandas library, i just learned how to read a csv file using pandas.

my data is actually raw packets i captured from sensor networks, to analyze corrupt packets.

what i have now is, thousands of rows and hundreds of columns, literally, and the values are all in Hex. i need to convert all the values to binary with trailing zeros.

i am at lost on how to accomplish that once i have read the CSV file successfully using pandas.

I'd appreciate every kind of help, even a simple direction.

here is my sample data:

> 00 FF FF 00 00 29 00 89 29 41 88 44 22 00 FF FF 01 00 3F 06 55 55 55
>   55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55
>   55 55 0A
>
> 00 FF FF 00 00 29 00 89 29 41 88 45 22 00 FF FF 01 00 3F 06 55 55 55
>   55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55
>   55 55 0A
>
> 00 FF FF 00 00 29 00 89 29 41 88 46 22 00 FF FF 01 00 3F 06 55 55 55
>   55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55
>   55 55 0A
>
> 00 FF FF 00 00 29 00 89 29 41 88 47 22 00 FF FF 01 00 3F 06 55 55 55
>   55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55 55
>   55 55 0A

Comment: You can find in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3258330/converting-from-hex-to-binary-without-losing-leading-0s-python a way to convert hex values to binary.

Comment: Can you post some sample raw input data

Comment: i did up there, check it out , @maeVeyable that wont work on dataframes.

Comment: Is this really your data? it has whitespace separators

Answer (score 0):

If I understood, in **column 1** you have **00**, **column 2** : **55**, ...

If I am right, you first need to concat three columns in a string `value = str(col1)+str(col2)+str(col3)` and then use the method to convert it in binary.

Comment: no, the columns and rows are fine as it is. i need the method to convert it to binary,

Comment: So, use directly `str()` on the value

Comment: i want to operate on dataframes, in pandas library