# Generate random binary strings of length 32

Tags: python

I want to generate 500 random binary strings of length 32 (i.e., from `00000...0` to `1111...1` where each string is length 32). I'm wondering how I could do this efficiently or Pythonically.

Right now, I randomly choose between `0` and `1` 32 times and then append the results into a string. This seems pretty inefficient and not pythonic. Is there some library functions i could use for this?

Comment: Just generate 32-bit random numbers and convert them to binary strings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random

rnd_32bit = f'{random.getrandbits(32):=032b}'
```

Comment: Simple and pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is probably to use the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) library (part of the python standard library as of python 3.6) and its `token_bytes` function.

```
import secrets

s = secrets.token_bytes(nbytes=4)
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815592/convert-bytes-to-bits-in-python) has various solutions for converting from `bytes` to a `str` of bit digits. You could do the following:

```
s = bin(int(secrets.token_hex(nbytes=4), 16))[2:].rjust(32, '0')
```

Throw this in a `for` loop and you're done!

---

In python 3.9 you also have the option of [`random.randbytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randbytes), e.g. `random.randbytes(4)`, which behaves similarly (though `secrets` will use a cryptographically secure source of randomness, if that matters to you).

Comment: Why would you get 32 *bytes* in order to get 32 *bits*?

Comment: Change `nbytes=4` and you might be onto something, however you still need to do the crux of the question, convert it to a binary *string*.

Comment: I misread that part, thanks. I'll update!

Comment: Closer, however I don't think bin outputs 32-bits, it may need to be padded with zeros to be 32 bits all the time...

Comment: @RonBeyer that's easy to fix: [Converting from hex to binary without losing leading 0's python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3258330/5987).

Comment: @MarkRansom Of course it is... but it should be in this answer (or linked in the answer). I think it's fixed now, but I didn't DV.

Answer (score 0):

Since python 3.9 you can do it this way:

```py
from random import randbytes

def rand_32bit_string(byte_count):
    return "{0:b}".format(int.from_bytes(randbytes(4), "big"))
```